# Stream video from Android phone to Google glass

Tags: android, video-streaming, google-glass, google-gdk, google-mirror-api

I have new task in hand wherein I have to work on Google Glass POC. My main intention is to access a video file sitting in your phone and access/play it on the connected Google glass.
Preferably I have to implement using JavaScript or special library [WearScript](http://www.wearscript.com/).

I have done some R&D, the Eclipse and ADT is set. I am now facing following issues.

1. I am not getting any idea what should the architecture of the app. I think there must be a Glass companion app sitting on phone which will read the video file and act as a content provider to the app running on glass.
2. I do not have actual device (Google glass) and could not find any emulator that I can use with eclipse to install and debug the app.
3. is there any readymade frameworks that can help streaming videos from phone or directly from server. (video size is limited 30-40 mb)

It will be great and very helpful if anyone can guide me on above points. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Emulation can be done with the android emulator, but there is no substitute to having a real device, especially given the specifics of the glass controls and display. At least use it for a bit. Streaming video to Google glass use not really a good use case, it is possible but watching videos on such a display is not a great experience.

Comment: Agree that watching it on such display will not be that comfortable, you have any pointers about how that can be achieved?

Comment: You need to send the video from your device to the server(May be using the web service) and get the video from your server to your glass app.I am not sure if it is possible for an android app to communicate with your glass app.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hmm. If thats true then my whole POC base is getting collapsed.

Comment: Well, glassware can communicate with android apps via bluetooth.